# C compile error - #include "cmakeconfig.h" - No such file or directory

Tags: c

On a Linux Mint 64bit system using gcc

I'm trying to compile the MiniBrowser example included with the WebKit package that I downloaded. webkitgtk-2.22.3

I have successfully setup the WebKit library, but when I try to compile the Tools/MiniBrowser example I get the error message given in the question title.

NOTE: There is no file on my system called cmakeconfig.h

NOTE: There are a few files called CMakeLists.txt that I do not know what to do with.

NOTE: Compiled using:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0 gstreamer-1.0` -o main main.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0 gstreamer-1.0`
```

Comment: This is not the full error message. The install `cmakeconfig.h` file to your system. What OS are you running? Have you tried compiling and installing cmke? How do you compile the package? What compiler and compiler options are you using?

Comment: ***CMakeLists.txt that I do not know what to do with.*** use `CMake` to generate project files for your compiler. `cmakeconfig.h` is likely a file generated by `CMake` using rules in one of the `CMakeLists.txt` files or something included from that.

Answer (score 0):

As per the question comments. Use the Linux command cmake with the argument CMakeLists.txt which hopefully will generate the file cmakeconfig.h

```
$ cmake CMakeLists.txt
```